# Is a hole this big fixable on deck board?

Tags: wood, deck, rot

I want to fix my deck board it look like this (the hole is like one inch). I have researched and caulk and fillers don’t look like they can fill this giant hole.

[image]

Comment: Just a comment because I've never tried it, but it seems to me you could screw in another board underneath and then fill the hole since it will have support.

Comment: Body filler may work.

Comment: Fillers should work if done in layers and supported.  If you have a piece of similar looking wood, cut the hole bigger and glue in a other piece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drill/glue/dowel would work fine. If you don't want to go that route, (costly hole saw, etc), you could use filler.

For the sake of color, I'd avoid gray ('classic') Bondo -- they make a 'wood filler' version that's more wood colored. Eg: [Bondo wood filler](https://www.homedepot.com/p/3M-Bondo-12-fl-oz-Wood-Filler-30081/206680651). There are, of course, other two-part fillers on the market to choose from.

Knock out the loose bits inside the knot before you start.

Try to put a 3" exterior screw in from the underside that goes through the knot but doesn't push out above the top of the board. You'll want to predrill and countersink this. The purpose is to have something for the bondo to grab onto. Failing that, you could put a shorter screw in sideways from the top. Just predrill and make sure the head of the screw is below the deck surface.

Put some scrap underneath temporarily to act as a floor for the filler. A layer of wax paper of foil will keep the bondo from sticking to the scrap.

Following the bondo instructions, mix and fill the hole. You can do this in one step, as the bondo cures chemically. Mound it a little high over the deck surface and slice it off with a long blade just as it turns to stiff jello. (This will save you sanding time.)

Comment: This but leave scrap wood in and support with two small screws.   Should not be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

I would drill it and fit a dowel of the right size. Even a bit of broom handle could work.